# gcc and the order of operation in C if statement

Tags: c, gcc

I have a line of code that looks like this:

`if ((!s2->lines[i]->flags & ML_TWOSIDED) || (s2->lines[i]->backsector == s1))`

and gcc gives me saying:

`warning: suggest parentheses around operand of ‘!’ or change ‘&’ to ‘&&’ or ‘!’ to ‘~’ [-Wparentheses]`

So, I'm curious as since it does compile, what is gcc doing? Is it not-ing the entire first segment, or only `s2->lines[i]->flags`?

In other words, is gcc assuming:

`if (!(s2->lines[i]->flags & ML_TWOSIDED) || (s2->lines[i]->backsector == s1))`

or

`if (((!s2->lines[i]->flags) & ML_TWOSIDED) || (s2->lines[i]->backsector == s1))`

or perhaps something else?

Comment: I would guess that gcc is following the well-defined precedence and associativity rules in the C standard, so even referring to gcc is a bit of a red herring

Comment: The latter. Is that what you intended? Or did you really want `~` instead of `!`? The fact that we are asking all these question justifies the warning from gcc.

Comment: @kaylum, no idea to be honest - I'm reading through the doom source code and going through the warnings gcc gives out, I'm not too familiar with C so I'm looking to understand the logic here better.

Comment: @JohnColeman, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, gcc is assuming you meant

```
if (((!s2->lines[i]->flags) & ML_TWOSIDED) || (s2->lines[i]->backsector == s1))
```

since that's what the precedence rules of the language say.  But since that's almost certainly not what you want, gcc is suggesting that you write

```
if ((!(s2->lines[i]->flags & ML_TWOSIDED)) || (s2->lines[i]->backsector == s1))
```

instead.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Precedence - this was the word I was looking for but was drawing a blank. Now I can more easily look up more information on this with regards to C. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 3):

Unary operators always have higher precedence than binary ones, meaning that GCC sees your expression as

```
((!s2->lines[i]->flags) & ML_TWOSIDED) || (s2->lines[i]->backsector == s1)
```

And GCC is puzzled by the fact that you used a *logical* subexpression (`!` operator) as an operand of *bitwise* expression (`&` operator). While there's nothing illegal in this (and the behavior is well defined), this is still not something that is used very often. When bitwise and logical semantics is mixed, usually it is bitwise at lower level and logical at higher level, not the other way around.

For this reason GCC asks you to confirm your intent with some extra parenthesis. And it appears that GCC's concern is justified: this is indeed not what you wanted to write.

Answer (score 2):

*what is gcc doing?*  It is only *suggesting* a course of action based on some observed ambiguities and unconventional operator usage:

Your original statement:

```
if ((!s2->lines[i]->flags & ML_TWOSIDED) || (s2->lines[i]->backsector == s1))
```

The GCC warning:

warning: suggest parentheses around operand of ‘!’ or change ‘&’ to ‘&&’ or ‘!’ to ‘~’ [-Wparentheses]

`~` and `&` are bitwise operators
`!`, `||` and `&&` are logical operators

The warning is recognizing that you are using a *bitwise* and *logical* operator together in a way that is unconventional.  Although legal, and it will compile this way, GCC is asking if you meant to do that, and offering suggestions resulting from its analysis in the form of three options:

1) *warning: suggest parentheses around operand of ‘!’*

```
if ((!(s2->lines[i]->flags & ML_TWOSIDED)) || (s2->lines[i]->backsector == s1))
      ^                                 ^
```

2) *or change ‘&’ to ‘&&’*

```
if ((!s2->lines[i]->flags && ML_TWOSIDED) || (s2->lines[i]->backsector == s1))
                          ^^
```

3)  *or ‘!’ to ‘~’*

```
  if ((~s2->lines[i]->flags & ML_TWOSIDED) || (s2->lines[i]->backsector == s1)) 
       ^     to match       ^
```

Only you know what was intended.  My guess is a combination of 1) & 2):

```
if ((!(s2->lines[i]->flags && ML_TWOSIDED)) || (s2->lines[i]->backsector == s1))
      ^                    ^^            ^
```